# Android app not compatible with 4.0.4

Tags: android, manifest, target

I have a Samsung Galaxy SII (Sprint version Epic 4G Touch) running Cyanogen 9 (4.0.4 ICS). Screen density is at default.  On the market it says my app is compatible with API 8-16+ and supports screens from small-xtra large. For some reason it is still not compatible with my phone.  Does it have to do with my custom rom? or possibly the fact I'm running 4.0.4? All users that cannot install also seem to be running custom roms.

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.pwnsro.dayz"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.0.4" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"

    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".DayZActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Also my project.properties:

```
target=android-15
```

*Edit:
It seems only users of AOSP Roms on ICS are having compatibility issues.  I switched to a Samsung 4.0.4 rom and I was able to install this from the market.

Comment: What phone are you using? API 16+ should indicate that it will work up to and beyond unreleased 4.1.

Comment: uhh, first sentence of my post.. tells you my phone..

Comment: ...wow. This will teach me to get on SO right after waking up... Sorry for my ignorance. >_<

Comment: "For some reason it is still not compatible with my phone" What do you mean by this? Are you saying it doesn't show up in Google Play for your phone/Google Play says it's not compatible?

Comment: Correct.  From what I'm seeing in the manifest file it SHOULD be compatible with my phone, however (and I hate how the play store doesn't tell you why) the play store still thinks my phone is incompatible with the app.

Comment: any of you know what I can do to fix the incompatibility issue?

Comment: This might sound crazy,  but try removing the support screens tag altogether and/or move it below the application tag in your manifest.  Your linter might complain via warning but recompile your binary and upload to market. I know it sounds silly, but I had something similiar happen back when the first Samsung galaxy tab (the crappy 2.2 device) came out.  Doesnt hurt to try.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, thanks forgivegod.

Comment: Nope that did not work forgivegod.

Comment: have you try to completely remove (not move) all the supports-screens tag and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you happen to have copy protection set to ON in android developer console? Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/filters.html) page.

> To copy protect an application, set copy protection to "On" when you configure publishing options for your application. Google Play will not show copy-protected applications on developer devices or unreleased devices.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said this:

> I switched to a Samsung 4.0.4 rom and I was able to install this from the market.

I guess that the problem is/was your custom ROM. Have you tried another custom ROM? Maybe it is a problem with that specific ROM or Google Play don't recognize it as a compatible SO.

Comment: Both an AOKP rom and Cyanogen 9 mod rom are incompatible, hence my statement of it seems any AOSP ICS roms are incompatible for whatever reason. That's just for my phone, I've had other people try to run it on there AOSP custom roms and it says the same thing in the market.